# AS3 Constrain Object while Zooming/Panning with GestureEvent / MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zooming, gesture, pan

What I want to do is to keep my MovieClip (which is bigger than the viewport) from having its borders visible. Just like many apps do, e.g. Clash of Clans.

This way if you zoom in and zoom out or pan you will never see the stage under it.

If I was only to pan and not zoom it would be easy because I just had to calculate if my MC rectangle is within my stage and if yes i would just:

```
mc.x = 0 + mc.width / 2;
//or
mc.x = stage.StageWidth - (mc.width/2);
//or .... The same for y
```

Now the big problem is when I also zoom! And every time I come up with some code it doesn't work well. There are many examples for zooming via `GestureEvent` on the web but none of them keeps the MC constrained so you don't see the stage under it.

Can someone please provide an example for me. Lets say the stage is 480x720 and the mc is 1080x720!

You gotta pan and zoom while always covering the stage and the scale of mc will remain within 1-1.5.

---

Here is my current code:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoBox);

var isInBox: Boolean = false;
table.x = 203.1;
table.y = 360;
table.scaleX = 1;
table.scaleY = 1;

var mouseTimer: Timer;

function onPan(event: TransformGestureEvent): void
{
    if (!isInBox)
    {
        if (event.phase == GesturePhase.BEGIN)
        {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoBox);
        trace("noClick");
        }

        table.x += event.offsetX;
        table.y += event.offsetY;
        if (table.x > (table.width / 2))
        {
        table.x = table.width / 2;
        }
        if (table.x < stage.stageWidth - (table.width / 2))
        {
            table.x = stage.stageWidth - (table.width / 2)
        }
        if (table.y > (table.height / 2))
        {
            table.y = table.height / 2;
        }
        if (table.y < stage.stageHeight - (table.height / 2))
        {
            table.y = stage.stageHeight - (table.height / 2)
        }

        if (event.phase == GesturePhase.END)
        {
            if (mouseTimer !== null)
            {
                if (mouseTimer.running)
                {
                    mouseTimer.stop();
                    mouseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, enableClick);
                }
            }
            mouseTimer = new Timer(250);
            mouseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, enableClick);
            mouseTimer.start();
            trace("start");
        }
    }
}
function enableClick(e: TimerEvent)
{
    mouseTimer.stop();
    trace("stop");
    mouseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, enableClick);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoBox);
    trace("nowClick");
}
function gotoBox(e: MouseEvent)
{
// here it goes to another frame
}
```

I cannot add the zooming function because its a total disaster; I used something similar to the function `onZoom` in this link FlashAndMath

Because I needed to zoom in on a point and out from it, and that is the main issue as I have to move my `mc` around to make that point in the center WHILE I GOTTA MOVE IT TO MAKE MY WHOLE MC IN A CERTAIN BOUNDARY TO COVER THE STAGE! These too movements act against each other. If this last part is not clear ask me to explain more please:)

After having the right answer from LDMS I updated this question to avoid chat-discussions:)

Comment: If you show your current code for Zooming/Panning, I'll give you an example based off those.  It's pretty common scenario.

Comment: I'm gonna put it here, but before I just wanna say as I asked this question on my phone some mistakes have been made, such as the word "Constrain" which i didn't write it and it must be a word-suggestion and also the "StageWidth" which starts with lower case:)

Comment: When you say update I dont know what you mean, I can edit, send comment and also answer my Q so I did the third. Sorry.
And thanks for helping me many times;)

Comment: #LDMS its MOUSE_CLICK

Comment: Ok,  what you could probably do is listen on the capture phase and stop propagation of the event in your child mouse clicks.  I'm not sure how that affects guestures though (I've barely ever used guestures, and I'm not sure if cancelling a mouse down event would prevent a guesture from dispatching.  I'd have play around with it tomorrow to find out.

Comment: Look at my code i've already done that in a nice way. But the problem as i said in the comments is that mouseChildren must be set to false BEFORE Gesture_Zoom to avoid the event.localX from being affected. I just somehow need to get that localX only from my main mc!

Comment: That's easy enough to do with the localToGlobal & globalToLocal helper methods.  I"ve updated the answer - NOT TESTED though.   I figured you would want the guesture event completely cancelled when a child object is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do, is whenever you move or scale the object, check to make sure it's not going out of bounds.

So if you made a function called `forceBounds`, just call it anytime you scale or change the x/y:

```
        function forceBounds():void {
            //figure out the bounds to constrain to
            //the x, should be the farthest left it can go without the edge being seen on the right. To get this value just subtract the smaller width (stage) from the larger width (mc) - this should be a negative number
            var bounds:Rectangle = (stage.stageWidth - mc.width, stage.stageHeight - mc.height, mc.width - stage.stageWidth, mc.height - stage.stageHeight);

            if (mc.x > bounds.x + bounds.width) {
                mc.x = bounds.x + bounds.width;
            }
            else if (mc.x < bounds.x) {
                mc.x= bounds.x;
            }

            if (mc.y > bounds.y + bounds.height) {
                mc.y = bounds.y + bounds.height;
            }
            else if (mc.y < bounds.y) {
                mc.y = bounds.y;
            }
        }
```

---

Here is a full example I made in FlashPro:  (with an object on the the stage with an instance name of `mc` that is bigger than the stage bounds.

Zoom code taken from [FlashAndMath.com](http://www.flashandmath.com/mobile/zoompan/)

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.GesturePhase;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);

forceBounds();

function onPan(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
    trace("PAN");
    if(e.phase == GesturePhase.BEGIN){
        stage.removeEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
    }

    //localToGlobal is a helper method that converts a point to global coordinates
    var p:Point = DisplayObject(e.target).localToGlobal(new Point(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
    //conversely, global to local does the opposite
    p = mc.globalToLocal(p);

    mc.x = p.x;
    mc.y = p.y;

    forceBounds();

    if(e.phase == GesturePhase.END){
        stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
    }
}

function onZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void {
    trace("ZOOM");
    var container:MovieClip = mc;
    var locX:Number=event.localX;
    var locY:Number=event.localY;
    var stX:Number=event.stageX;
    var stY:Number=event.stageY;
    var prevScale:Number=container.scaleX;
    var mat:Matrix;
    var externalPoint=new Point(stX,stY);
    var internalPoint=new Point(locX,locY);

    container.scaleX *= (event.scaleX + event.scaleY) * .5;

    if(event.scaleX > 1 && container.scaleX > 6){
        container.scaleX=prevScale;
    }
    if(event.scaleY > 1 && container.scaleY > 6){
        container.scaleX=prevScale;
    }
    if(event.scaleX < 1 && container.scaleX < 0.8){
        container.scaleX=prevScale;
    }
    if(event.scaleY < 1 && container.scaleY < 0.8){
        container.scaleX=prevScale;
    }

    if(container.scaleX < 1) container.scaleX = 1;
    if(container.scaleX > 1.5) container.scaleX = 1.5;
    container.scaleY = container.scaleX;

    mat=container.transform.matrix.clone();
    MatrixTransformer.matchInternalPointWithExternal(mat,internalPoint,externalPoint);
    container.transform.matrix=mat;

    forceBounds();
}

function forceBounds():void {
    //figure out the bounds to constrain to
    //the x, should be the farthest left it can go without the edge being seen on the right. To get this value just subtract the smaller width (stage) from the larger width (mc) - this should be a negative number
    var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(stage.stageWidth - mc.width, stage.stageHeight - mc.height, mc.width - stage.stageWidth, mc.height - stage.stageHeight);

    if (mc.x > bounds.x + bounds.width) {
        mc.x = bounds.x + bounds.width;
    }
    else if (mc.x < bounds.x) {
        mc.x= bounds.x;
    }

    if (mc.y > bounds.y + bounds.height) {
        mc.y = bounds.y + bounds.height;
    }
    else if (mc.y < bounds.y) {
        mc.y = bounds.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code worked for me with a few manipulations as my mc's orientation point is at the center. But now I'm facing another issue, because I have other movieClips inside the main mc we are working with here, when I zoom over those movieclips the result is weird and I think it comes from:
    var locX:Number=event.localX;
    var locY:Number=event.localY;
if you think I'm right, please tell me how can I get those values from my main mc not those inside it.

Comment: I just realized this weird thing happens not only when there's another mc under my finger but also when there is one between my two fingers even not being touched!

Comment: You probably should do `mc.mouseChildren = false`,  if you need the children to dispatch mouse events, then you'll need to translate the `event.scaleX` and `event.offsetX/Y` to be relative to the parent (`mc`) not the child that dispatched the event.

Comment: I added mc.mouseChildren = false to the first line of onPan and onZoom, but it won't help unless those functions are called at least once. because the vary first time onPan and onZoom are called my mc.children are still affected by mouse so its already late. The second+ times I pan or zoom your idea works fine.

Comment: And as I need to re-enable those mouseChildren again (even by a TimerEvent delay) so there will always be one first run of onZoom and  onPan with those mouseChildren set to true!

Comment: why do you have to wait until a zoom or pan to set it? why not just set right away when app starts?

Comment: Because I need those children to interact with mouse:) There are tons of them inside my main mc.

Comment: I actually tried what you said and it worked great for zooming or panning but they wont respond to my mouseEvents

Comment: Well that complicates it then.  What kind of mouse/touch events are the children listening for? CLICK? Gestures? Click/TouchDown?

Comment: #LDMS did you delete those lines including localToGlobal and etc? Anyways, It wont work because we dont know what movieClip in under that point, it could be a child of a child of a child...! Maybe I better add a new Question on stackoverflow asking "how to return the localX for a mouse event of a certain chosen movieClip, regardless of other movieClips below/over/in it having any possible index?"

Comment: your last edit (global and local) is almost the right answer. You just mazed yourself a bit;) Thanks for every thing.

Comment: Do you mean I put them in backwards?  (I have a doozy of a head cold right now so it wouldn't surprise me).  Suggest an edit if you'd like so future visitors can see what worked.  Though I'm not sure if you have sufficient rep to suggest edits yet.